# Rounding a number to the nearest 5 or 10 or X

Tags: vba, rounding

Given numbers like 499, 73433, 2348 what VBA can I use to round to the nearest 5 or 10? or an arbitrary number?

By 5:

```
 499 ->  500
2348 -> 2350
7343 -> 7345
```

By 10:

```
 499 ->  500
2348 -> 2350
7343 -> 7340
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your answers. I'm the smarter for it. Sorry I can only mark a single ressponse as correct, as the real "answer" was scattered across several messages.

Comment: This works for me http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5031

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Integrated Answer**

```
X = 1234 'number to round
N = 5    'rounding factor
round(X/N)*N   'result is 1235
```

For floating point to integer, 1234.564 to 1235, (this is VB specific, most other languages simply truncate) do:

```
int(1234.564)   'result is 1235
```

*Beware:* VB uses [Bankers Rounding](http://wiki.c2.com/?BankersRounding), to the nearest even number, which can be surprising if you're not aware of it:

```
msgbox round(1.5) 'result to 2
msgbox round(2.5) 'yes, result to 2 too
```

*Thank you everyone.*

Answer (score 95):

It's simple math. Given a number X and a rounding factor N, the formula would be:

round(X / N)*N

Answer (score 12):

To round to the nearest X (without being VBA specific)

N = X * int(N / X + 0.5)

Where int(...) returns the next lowest whole number.

If your available rounding function already rounds to the **nearest** whole number then omit the addition of 0.5

Comment: Just to clarify: `int(N+0.5)` is the same as `round(N)`

Answer (score 9):

In VB, math.round has additional arguments to specify number of decimal places and rounding method.  **Math.Round(10.665, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)** will return 10.67 .  If the number is a decimal or single data type, math.round returns a decimal data type.  If it is double, it returns double data type. That might be important if option strict is on.

The result of (10.665).ToString("n2") rounds away from zero to give "10.67".  without additional arguments math.round returns 10.66, which could lead to unwanted discrepancies.

Answer (score 3):

'Example: Round 499 to nearest 5. You would use the ROUND() FUNCTION.

```
a = inputbox("number to be rounded")
 b = inputbox("Round to nearest _______ ")


  strc = Round(A/B)
  strd = strc*B


 msgbox( a & ",  Rounded to the nearest " & b & ", is" & vbnewline & strd)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a strict Visual Basic approach, you can convert the floating-point value to an integer to round to said integer.  VB is one of the rare languages that rounds on type conversion (most others simply truncate.)

Multiples of 5 or x can be done simply by dividing before and multiplying after the round.

If you want to round and keep decimal places, Math.round(n, d) would work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is our solution:

```
Public Enum RoundingDirection
    Nearest
    Up
    Down
End Enum

Public Shared Function GetRoundedNumber(ByVal number As Decimal, ByVal multiplier As Decimal, ByVal direction As RoundingDirection) As Decimal
    Dim nearestValue As Decimal = (CInt(number / multiplier) * multiplier)
    Select Case direction
        Case RoundingDirection.Nearest
            Return nearestValue
        Case RoundingDirection.Up
            If nearestValue >= number Then
                Return nearestValue
            Else
                Return nearestValue + multiplier
            End If
        Case RoundingDirection.Down
            If nearestValue <= number Then
                Return nearestValue
            Else
                Return nearestValue - multiplier
            End If
    End Select
End Function
```

Usage:

```
dim decTotal as Decimal = GetRoundedNumber(CDec(499), CDec(0.05), RoundingDirection.Up)
```

Comment: I think this is VB.NET not VBA?  The logic is useful though!

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
'nearest
 n = 5
 'n = 10

 'value
 v = 496
 'v = 499 
 'v = 2348 
 'v = 7343

 'mod
 m = (v \ n) * n

 'diff between mod and the val
 i = v-m


 if i >= (n/2) then     
      msgbox m+n
 else
      msgbox m
 end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply ROUND(x/5)*5 should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comment so I will use this

in a vbs run that and have fun figuring out why the 2 give a result of 2

you can't trust round

```
 msgbox round(1.5) 'result to 2
 msgbox round(2.5) 'yes, result to 2 too
```

Comment: I'd say that it either has something to do with the way floating point numbers are stored, or a correct implementation of the internationally standartized rounding algorithm. I don't know it's name, but it was so that every other .5 was rounded down, and the rest up.

Comment: Rounding rounds [sic] to the nearest even number.

There is even an explanation here in SO.

Comment: Vilx, your suggestion is good, but not for VBA round(465 / 10)*10 will return 460

Comment: Well, that's FP math for you, get over it.  Most FP numbers ending in 0.5 will actually be a tiny fraction either above or below the required value, and that affects the rounding.

Comment: @Manuel, I think that's called Bankers rounding (nearest even number), one of the MANY variants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

--------------start----------------

```
Function Round_Up(ByVal d As Double) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    result = Math.Round(d)
    If result >= d Then
        Round_Up = result
    Else
        Round_Up = result + 1
    End If
End Function
```

-------------end ------------

Answer (score 0):

I slightly updated the function provided by the "community wiki" (the best answer), just to round to the nearest 5 (or anything you like), with this exception : **the rounded number will NEVER be superior to the original number**.

This is useful in cases when it is needed to say that *"a company is alive for 47 years"* : I want the web page to display **"is alive for more than 45 years"**, while avoiding lying in stating **"is alive for more than 50 years"**.

So when you feed this function with 47, it will not return 50, but will return 45 instead.

```
'Rounds a number to the nearest unit, never exceeding the actual value
function RoundToNearestOrBelow(num, r)

    '@param         num         Long/Integer/Double     The number to be rounded
    '@param         r           Long                    The rounding value
    '@return        OUT         Long                    The rounded value

    'Example usage :
    '   Round 47 to the nearest 5 : it will return 45
    '   Response.Write RoundToNearestBelow(47, 5)

    Dim OUT : OUT = num

    Dim rounded : rounded = Round((((num)) / r), 0) * r

    if (rounded =< num) then
        OUT = rounded
    else
        OUT = rounded - r
    end if

    'Return
    RoundToNearestOrBelow = OUT

end function 'RoundToNearestOrBelow
```

Answer (score -2):

To mimic in Visual Basic the way the round function works in Excel, you just have to use: 
WorksheetFunction.Round(number, decimals)

This way the banking or accounting rounding don't do the rounding.

Comment: This won't round 2348 to 2350 as requested in the question (second example).