# round up to next multiple of 10 vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, rounding

How can I round a value UP to the next multiple of 10 in VB ?

e.g.

```
19 -> 20
35 -> 40
21 -> 30
```

I found so things saying use a round function but when i type it in to my IDE (Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015) it doesn't recognise it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Googling `round up to next multiple of 10 in visual basic` seems to yield plenty of results, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326476/how-to-round-a-number-in-vba-to-the-nearest-5-or-10-or-x. There seem to be more ways than just `round()`

Comment: i've tried this but it doesn't recognise round    `round(X/N)*N`

Comment: thanks @CodeiSir that worked perfectly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To round up use the `ceiling` function. (info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
myNumber = Math.Ceiling(myNumber / 10) * 10
```

Deviding it first by 10 and then multiplying it again with 10 will do the trick.

**Update:** in case you are wondering, there are no problems with Integer

Comment: This isn't a great solution. The only two overloads of `Math.Ceiling` available are for either `Double` or `Decimal`. In the case of `Integer` the call to `Math.Ceiling` gets cast to `Double`. This could lead to rounding errors.

Comment: Downvoting means "This answer is not usefull", why did you downvote? Of cause using function has the effects of the funtions, and for this its more then OK to use it.

Comment: Downvoting is used for answers that "are least useful", and not "not useful". In your answer you're doing some type casting which only works with `Option Strict Off`. If you set `Option Strict On` then this code won't even compile. This is not a good robust solution.

Comment: You are saying nobody should ever use `Math.Ceiling`, but thats just your opinion. The answer is in no way wrong. He wanted to use `round` anyway, so thats exactly what he was looking for.

Comment: By the way, a 32bit Integer is perfectly represented by double. The function is perfectly suited for Integer. In case you are wondering, it also has a Decimal overload.

Comment: @Enigmativity `Math.Ceiling(CDec(myNumber) / 10) * 10` compiles fine, even with `Option Sctrict On`

Comment: @Jeroen - Not when you're assigning it back to `myNumber`, as in `myNumber = Math.Ceiling(myNumber / 10) * 10`.

Comment: @CodeiSir - I'm saying that you shouldn't use `Math.Ceiling` for any other types other than `Double` or `Decimal`. Spotting bugs based on implicit casting is hard. Someone will come, read this answer, adapt it to a different situation and get a bug.

Comment: @Enigmativity Pedantic much? :-) Try `thisNum = (Math.Ceiling(CDec(thisNum) / 10) * 10).ToString` Tadaa! Problem solved

Comment: @CodeiSir - The fact that he wanted to use `Round` shows that he doesn't understand about the issues with implicit casting. Suggesting `Ceiling` just compounds the confusion.

Comment: @Jeroen - That doesn't compile either. The type of `myNumber` (or `thisNum` as you put it) is `Integer`. The issue with this not compiling with `Option Strict On` is that the compiler is telling you it is bad to do. Sure you can explicitly cast, but that's just throwing caution to the wind.

Comment: thisNum is a String :-)

Comment: @Jeroen - That's fine, but the code that I said didn't compile it was `Integer`.

Comment: @Enigmativity the fact that he wanted to use `round`, shows that he was very well aware of the effects of implicit casting  And even if he had Integer first and then Double (wich don't know at all) he would be warned when using strict.

Comment: @CodeiSir - I don't think so. Strict is off by default. As I already said I think that implication of him asking for `Round` is the other way.

Comment: @Enigmativity so if it's not a problem when strict is on, what's the problem if its off ? 

Comment: @CodeiSir - When strict is on your code won't compile - so it **is** a problem. Strict is off by default to handle the "loose" behaviour that VB6 brought to VB.NET. Turning strict on brings VB.NET up to the same rigorous type-safety as C#. Type-safety in a strongly-typed language is usually a pretty good thing.

Comment: Following your logic, you should go find any post using any implicit typecasting and down vote it. *ridiculous*

Answer (score -2):

This is an `Integer`-based solution.

```
myNumber = If(myNumber Mod 10 = 0, myNumber, If(myNumber > 0, 10, 0) + 10 * (myNumber \ 10))
```

It doesn't suffer from rounding and is also is at least 2x faster than using `Math.Ceiling`.

Comment: Math.Ceiling doesn't suffer precision on Integers. You can represent a up to 53bit Integer in double without loss, however VB only uses a 32bit Integer. Thats why Integer can be converted to Double anytime. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Also good luck with `mod` on doubles.

Comment: @CodeiSir - Where is the `mod` on doubles?

Comment: @Enigmativity the OP's question doesn't explicitly define the inputs as `integer`, you interpreted it as such. I thought the "thisNum is a string" would be enough of a hint to that fact :-) If I ever need to do this with an  `integer` though, your method gets my vote!

Comment: @Jeroen - Where do you get the "thisNum is a string" from? It's not in the OP's question or any comments.

Comment: @Enigmativity I made that remark as a joke, you even responded to it.

Comment: @Jeroen - Sorry, I don't get the joke.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are forgiven :-)