# clng/cint/round in VBS and Classic ASP and VBA wrong round

Tags: vba, vbscript, asp-classic, rounding, numeric

Why ASP and VBS when rounding if the integer part is odd and the decimal part is 5 the results go down, even when the result goes up ?

Please try it yourself:

```
a=1.5 
wscript.echo clng(a)   '---> 2 

a=2.5 
wscript.echo clng(a)   '---> 2 

a=3.5 
wscript.echo clng(a)   '---> 4 

a=4.5 
wscript.echo clng(a)   '---> 4

a=5.5 
wscript.echo clng(a)   '---> 6

a=6.5 
wscript.echo clng(a)   '---> 6
```

### How is it possible? I haven't found any documentation about this...

Sorry , the question is why for default VBS/ASP e VBA usr Banker's rounding?

Comment: *"I haven't found **any** documentation about this"* - I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: You don't want it to round use [`Int() or Fix()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4dseb50%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) respectively.

Comment: Although not VBScript *(VBA but difference is minimal)* this answer gives a good explanation of the behaviour - [How to round a number in VBA to the nearest 5? (or 10 or X)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12731182/692942)

Comment: I think it is absurd that by default all function VBS / ASP and VBA use the banker's rounding.

Answer (score 4):

> <sup>From [The Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842(v=vs.84).aspx)</sup>
>   *When the fractional part of a value is exactly `0.5`, the `CLng` function rounds to the closest even number. For example, `0.5` rounds to `0`, `1.5` rounds to `2`, and `3.5` rounds to `4`. The purpose of rounding to the
>   **closest even number** is to compensate for a bias that could accumulate when many numbers are added together.*
>
> *`CLng` differs from the `Fix` and `Int` functions, which truncate, rather than round, the fractional part of a number.*

Comment: Amazing!, documentation and exactly where you'd expect it to be! :o

Comment: VBA tip for reference: https://www.599cd.com/tips/access/130708-bankers-rounding/